# If $\operatorname{var}(X) =0$ then $p( X = E (X)) = 1.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance

Let $X$ be a random variable.
Then $\operatorname{var}(X) =0$ implies $p( X = E (X)) = 1.$

Actually i need both directions. But i was able to show that  $p( X = E (X)) = 1$ implies $\operatorname{var}(X) =0.$ So all i need is the other direction.

I think we have to use the definition of the variance and set the $\operatorname{var}(X) = 0.$ But why is $p(X = E(X)) = 1$?

Comment: Follows from Chebyshev's inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Shorter:

$(X-\Bbb{E}[X])^2 \geq 0$ by definition. So it follows directly from $\Bbb{E}[(X-\Bbb{E}[X])^2] = \operatorname{Var}(X) = 0$, that $(X-\Bbb{E}[X])^2 = 0$ almost surely. We conclude $X-\Bbb{E}[X] = 0$ almost surely. That is what you wanted to show.

Comment: The length of my answer is basically the missing justification of your "so it follows directly" sentence, which might not be entirely obvious to someone who needed to ask the original question.

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) trick: try using `\operatorname{Var}` to get upright letters like $\operatorname{Var}(X)$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for sake of contradiction $P(X \ne E[X]) > 0$.
Then there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $$P(|X - E[X]| > \epsilon) > 0.$$
But then
$$\text{Var}(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2] \ge E[(X - E[X])^2 \mathbf{1}_{|X - E[X]| > \epsilon}] > \epsilon^2 P(|X - E[X]| > \epsilon) > 0,$$
a contradiction.

---

If the above is hard to understand, considering the case of a discrete random variable $X$ can be helpful for intuition. If $P(X \ne E[X]) > 0$, then there is some value $c \ne E[X]$ such that $P(X=c) > 0$. Then
$$\text{Var}(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2] \ge (c - E[X])^2 P(X=c) > 0.$$
This argument does not work for continuous random variables, though.